# Combinatorics Problem on proving that a particular sum is 0

Tags: combinatorics, summation, products

I'm having some issues with proving that the following sum is $0$ for any value of $n \geq 2$:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n}(a_{j}-a_{i})}
$$

where the $a_i$ are non-zero and positive. Just wondering if anyone had any pointers, the first few cases are easy to verify, i.e $n=2,3$.

So for $n=2$ the sum reads:

$$
\frac{1}{a_2 -a_1}+\frac{1}{a_1-a_2} = 0
$$

and for $n=3$ it would be
$$
\frac{1}{(a_{3}-a_{1})(a_{2}-a_{1})}+\frac{1}{(a_1-a_2)(a_3-a_2)}+\frac{1}{(a_1-a_3)(a_2-a_3)} = 0, 
$$
it's just the general case I'm struggling to find an argument for. Thanks!

Comment: The notation $\prod_{i\neq j}^{n}(a_{j}-a_{i})$ is somehow ambiguous. Do you mean $\prod_{\substack{i=1 \\ i \neq j}}^{n}(a_{j}-a_{i})$?

Comment: That is correct, yes, apologies for the misprint

Comment: Have altered slightly.

Comment: You could try with [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The degree of the polynomial

$$q(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{\substack{i=1 \\ i \neq j}}^{n}\frac{x-a_i}{a_{j}-a_{i}}-1$$ is $n-1$ and the $a_j$ for $1 \le j \le n$ are $n$ roots. Therefore $q$ is the always vanishing polynomial and $q$ leading coefficient which is
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{i=1 \\ i \neq j}}^{n}(a_{j}-a_{i})}$$ is equal to zero.

*Note: all this is closely related to Lagrange polynomials.*

Comment: In the formula for $q$, $X$ should be $x$.

Comment: Very nice solution, I thought by the appearance of the sum that there would be some sort of link to Lagrange polynomials, but I didn't see it! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer... but maybe useful**

Let $p$ be the polynomial $p(x) = (x-a_1) \dots (x-a_n)$. Then for $1 \le j \le n$

$$p^\prime(a_j)= \prod_{\substack{i=1 \\ i \neq j}}^{n}(a_{j}-a_{i})$$ and the result to be proven is equivalent to

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{p^\prime(a_j)} = 0.$$ However, I don't know how to prove that for the time being...

One can also notice that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a_j} \frac{x-a_j}{p(x)} = \frac{1}{p^\prime(a_j)}.$$

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I had tried a similar thing myself as the problem originally comes from me studying the polynomial $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ as you have written it, and I first noted that $1/p = \frac{1}{\prod_{i \neq 1}^{m}(a_{1}-a_{i})}\frac{1}{x-a_{1}} + \frac{1}{\prod_{i \neq 2}^{m}(a_{2}-a_{i})}\frac{1}{x-a_{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\prod_{i \neq m}^{m}(a_{m}-a_{i})}\frac{1}{x-a_{m}}$

Comment: I wrote another answer which is now complete.