# Help me to get deeper understanding of Euler's proof of his Arithmetical Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-explanation, products, partial-fractions

With distinct numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, let's denote the products of the differences of each of these numbers with the each of the rest of them by the following principle:

\begin{align}
    (a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)\dots(a_1-a_n) &= \prod_{1\lt j\leqslant n}(a_1-a_j) = \mu_1, \\
    (a_2-a_1)(a_2-a_3)(a_2-a_4)\dots(a_2-a_n) &= \prod_{\substack{1\leqslant j\leqslant n \\ j\neq 2}}(a_2-a_j) = \mu_2, \\
    (a_3-a_1)(a_3-a_2)(a_3-a_4)\dots(a_3-a_n) &= \prod_{\substack{1\leqslant j\leqslant n \\ j\neq 3}}(a_3-a_j) = \mu_3, \\
    &\ \ \vdots \\
    (a_n-a_1)(a_n-a_2)(a_n-a_3)\dots(a_n-a_{n-1}) &= \prod_{1\leqslant j\lt n}(a_2-a_j) = \mu_n
\end{align}

There is a theorem that the sum of reciprocals of that resulting sequence will always be equal to $0$:

\begin{align}
    \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\mu_i}=\dfrac{1}{\mu_1}+\dfrac{1}{\mu_2}+\ldots+\dfrac{1}{\mu_n}=0
\end{align}

There also is a more general claim that for any integer $\xi$, $0\leqslant\xi\lt n-1$ (in other words, $\xi$ is a nonnegative integer which is less than the number of factors in each $\mu$, which happens to be exactly $n-1$), the result is just the same:

\begin{align}
    \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{a_i^{\xi}}{\mu_i}=\dfrac{a_1^{\xi}}{\mu_1}+\dfrac{a_2^{\xi}}{\mu_2}+\ldots+\dfrac{a_n^{\xi}}{\mu_n}=0
\end{align}

Leonhard Euler provides a very similar theorem in his **Institutionum Calculi Integralis, Vol. II**, §1169 (available in English [here](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/intcalvol1/part5ch3.pdf), see page 26 of this document), and the way he proves it seems quite confusing to me. I have a couple of questions related to this theorem:

1. Does this theorem have a special name, or is it just a generic fact?
2. In Corollary 1 (§1170), Euler claims that in case if $\xi\geqslant n-1$ the sum *no longer vanishes* (i.e. is no longer equal to zero because in this case $\xi$ is out of bounds mentioned in the theorem), but is equal to $\dfrac{1}{N}$ instead. But, due to $N$ not being defined directly in the mentioned corollary, how to understand what $N$ is equal to in $\dfrac{1}{N}$? It is known to me that $N=1$ in case $\xi = n-1$, and that $\dfrac{1}{N}=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ in case $\xi=n$. What happens to $N$ in case $\xi\gt n$?

   After more thorough reading, I believe that $N$ might be the real polynomial function in the denominator of a proper rational function $\dfrac{1}{N}$, according to  Euler's **Introductione ad Analysin Infinitorum, Ch. II**, §40 (available in English [here](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/introductiontoanalysisvolone/ch2vol1.pdf), see page 41 of this document), which Euler himself seems to be referencing.
3. Can you explain **Euler's** proof of the theorem in question rigorously, so it's clearly seen what goes from where?

**Edit:** in my search for something to improve the question, I've found some useful references that can help.

- Case $\xi = 0$ had been reviewed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008243/). The currently accepted answer makes use of [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), while Euler seems to have a much more basic proof through [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), which makes the essence of my question different.
- Case $\xi = n-1$ had been mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016616/). The currently accepted answer is based on a polynomial analysis, thus it's also different from what I'm looking for.
- Finally, $\xi = n$ is mentioned in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619148/). I've got an elegant answer based on Vandermonde determinant and polynomial analysis, and it's not too much of what I am looking for.